# Looking for a javascript callback action to re-initiate a custom slideshow in gutenberg

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, block-editor

I'm using the new Gutenberg Blocks in ACF to build a custom slider, but I need a way to re-initiate BXSlider(the library I'm using for the slider) after every change made on the block.  I'm looking in the documentation for what the gutenberg block callback function is after every change/update, but cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  I can include a javascript with callback function for each block in the ACF documentation.